# Problemas em chamada PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Estou com um problema em chamar um programa pelo `PHP` passando parâmetros.

Código:

```
<?
    print("<script language=javascript>
       alert(\" <<<  Dados Alterados com Sucesso!  >>>\");
       if($w_rec != "")
       {
           if (confirm(\"Deseja alterar as demais opções?\") == true)
           {
             location.replace(\"../sai_cada_peri/sai_frm_alte_peri.php?$w_rec+$w_cont\");
           }
           else{
            parent.location.replace(\"../sai_cada_peri/sai_alte_peri.php\");
            }
        }
        else{
            parent.location.replace(\"../sai_cada_peri/sai_alteperi.php\");
        }    
      </script>"); 
?>
```

Nesse trecho do `PHP` ele vai verificar se o `$w_rec` está vazio, e se caso esteja e o usuário confirmar ele vai chamar outro programa passando esses parâmetros. O meu problema é .. Como passar esses parâmetros nessa chamada?

A chamada em que me refiro seria nessa linha:

```
location.replace(\"../sai_cada_peri/sai_frm_alte_peri.php?$w_rec+$w_cont\");
```

**Obs*** O programa num todo é só `PHP`.

Comment: Mas... isso é JavaScript! Será que o problema não é só a falta de aspas e *escape* em `if($w_rec != "")`? Tente `if('$w_rec' != '')`

Comment: Sim, em si essa parte trata-se de um JavaScript! Mas as variáveis que quero passar estão em PHP **location.replace(\"../sai_cada_peri/sai_frm_alte_peri.php?$w_rec+$w_cont\");**

Comment: Não está claro qual é o problema. Se está dando erro nesse JS, acho melhor postar o código gerado pelo PHP (a saída que o browser enxerga).

Comment: Suponho que não possa ser o caso das aspas. Pois como @bfavaretto pediu para mim tentar, o programa ainda não roda!

Comment: Mas precisamos ver a saída desse PHP pra entender melhor! De um "exibir código-fonte" no seu browser e poste o JS que seu PHP cuspiu.

Comment: Sim era problema com aspas. Desculpem-me pelo problema, ele estava dando erro pois eu não coloquei as aspas na passagem de parâmetro (\"../sai_cada_peri/sai_frm_alte_peri.php?'$w_rec'+'$w_cont'\");

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é sobre um problema específico e não ajudará mais ninguém.

Comment: Esta pergunta está a ser discutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1957/7210

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Evite misturar linguagens de servidor e de cliente no mesmo código

Esta pratica dificulta a manutenção e engessa o seu código. O ideal é que você separe as camadas de código e passe as informações necessárias via um objeto ou como parâmetros para uma função, por exemplo.

Exemplo prático:

```
function sucesso(w_rec, w_cont){
    alert("<<<  Dados Alterados com Sucesso!  >>>");
    if(w_rec != ""){
        if(confirm("Deseja alterar as demais opções?") == true){
            location.replace("../sai_cada_peri/sai_frm_alte_peri.php?" + Number(w_rec+w_cont));
        }else{
            parent.location.replace("../sai_cada_peri/sai_alte_peri.php");
        }
    }else{
        parent.location.replace("../sai_cada_peri/sai_alteperi.php");
    }
}
```

E ai você passa suas variáveis PHP para a função JavaScript:

```
sucesso(<?php echo $w_rec ?>, <?php echo $w_cont ?>);
```

Answer (score 2):

Peço desculpa ia tentar ajudar mas como não concordo com a forma do que está exposto prefiro recomendar o seguinte:

primeiro: Passar o conteúdo para variaveis javascript... exemplo: no html...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var w_rec = '<?php echo $w_rec ?>';
    var w_cont = '<?php echo $w_cont ?>';
</script>
```

depois utilizar o mesmo código mas em puro javascript... que qualquer editor pode ajudar! Penso ser mais simples, intuitivo e mais gerível dentro do projeto.