# Passar parametros em PHP

Tags: php

Bem essa é uma pergunta muito tosca (Eu sei), mas não sei como passar os dados para outro programa no php! Onde eu utilizo:

```
<?
print("<script language=javascript>
          alert(\"Dados alterados !!\");
          location.replace("../sai_cada/sai_frm_alte.php?$e_per+$e_cont);
          </script>"); 
?>
```

Eu quero passar o `$e_per` e o `$e_cont` para o programa `sai_frm_alte`, mas não sei como deveria ficar a passagem no php! 
E mais uma .. Como eu estou passando eles com o `$` como eu deveria pegar no próximo programa?
Atualmente eu utilizo o :

```
$w_tx_nota = $_GET['w_tx_nota'];
```

Essa seria a maneira correta?

Comment: Sim. `sai_cada/sai_frm_alte.php?nome_var=$e_per&nome_var=$e_cont`

Comment: Acho que estão a fazer o mesmo trabalho de casa :D

Comment: Não @JorgeB. pois nesse ele não resolveu o meu problema !

Comment: Esta resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31948/7210 não resolve o teu problema?

Comment: Não, pois no caso dele, ele queria passar diretamente utilizando javascript tendo algumas verificações' logo em meu caso só quero determinar tais parametros'

Comment: Não estou a perceber a diferença. É só retirar as verificações. O resto é igual.

Comment: "Essa seria a maneira correta?" Sim, você está passando dados pela URL, logo usa-se *GET*. Sua URL deve ser: `"../sai_cada/sai_frm_alte.php?e_per=$e_per&e_cont=$e_cont` e recuperar com: `$_GET['e_per']` ou `$_GET['e_cont']`